# In Django Unite a Dynamic Amount of QuerySets

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

In my django-application I have a model with “UnitNodes”, “Persons”, and “PersonUnitRelations”. I wish to select all persons related to a list of units. I think it is most efficent if I can do things in only one DB query. So I cam up with some code similar to this:

```
from models import Person
from django.db.models import Q
from models import UnitNode

unitqs = UnitNode.objects.order_by('translations__title').filter(Q(translations__title__icontains="ceres"))
unit = unitqs[0]
qs = Person.objects.filter(personunitrelation__unit_node=unitqs[0])
for unit in unitqs:
    qs2 = Person.objects.filter(personunitrelation__unit_node=unit)
    qs = qs.union(qs2)
```

This can create some large query and I wonder if there is some better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Two queries

Yes, simply use the [**`__in`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#in) lookup:

```
qs = Person.objects.filter(personunitrelation__unit_node__in=unitqs)
```

This will ten result in something like:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM person AS p
JOIN personunitrelation AS pur ON pur.person_id = p.id
WHERE pur.unit_node_id IN (14, 25)
```

where `14` and `25` are here *hypothentical* `id`s of the `UnitNode`s. This thus will take two queries: one to fetch the `UnitNode`s, and one to fetch the `Person`s.

## One query

You can even here make it a *single* query, if you are not interested in the `unitqs` with:

```
Person.objects.filter(
    personunitrelation__unit_node__translations__title__icontains="ceres"
)
```

Which will result in something like:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM person AS p
JOIN personunitrelation AS pur ON pur.person_id = p.id
JOIN unit_node AS un ON pur.unit_node = un.id
JOIN ON translation AS t ON t.unit_node = un.id
WHERE t.title LIKE '%ceres%'
```

(simplified version)